# Adding an image above each item in table of contents page before chapters

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

Any examples online, on how to add images/styles to the table of contents - specifically, I want to add an image above each chapter section in the table of content page

Table of Contents

(image here)

chapter 1 .... p22

sections etc

(image here)

chapter 2 .....p33

sections etc

...

Any tips or examples online on how to do this easily?

Thanks

Jim

Comment: What document class are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\tocfig}[2][]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \bigskip\noindent\fi%
    \protect\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\par}%
    }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\tocfig[height=15mm]{example-image}
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\tocfig[height=15mm]{example-image}
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\end{document}
```

[image]